# Get and modify crawled property

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I have a custom metadata mapped now by script I need to get that to do some update.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question you need to use this command:

```
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty
```

for example:

```
$searchapp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$cat = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCategory –SearchApplication $searchapp –Identity CATEGORYID
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty -SearchApplication $searchapp -Category $cat –Limit 1
```

You have to exec this command with farm permissions.

Comment: how can I then modify the properties?